# preg_replace use matched pattern in replacement

Tags: php, regex

I want to ask if it's possible to use a matched regex pattern in determining the replacement from an array. For example

```
$rpl['brat'] = 'qwerty';
$rpl['omri'] = 'asdfgh';

$str1 = 'abc brat bca';
$str2 = 'abc omri bca';

print_r(preg_replace('#bc (.+?) bc#'), $rpl[$1], $str1)); // aqwertya
print_r(preg_replace('#bc (.+?) bc#'), $rpl[$1], $str2)); // aasdfgha
```

Now obviously `$1` is incorrect syntax, but this is just to show the point I'm making. How can I do this?

Comment: @devnull burn in hell for suggesting that.

Comment: Well that escalated quickly

Comment: @YUNOWORK Could you please _lead_ me there?

Comment: @php_nub_qq Why dont you use a foreach loop for that?

Comment: @YUNOWORK because I wasn't sure if there was such an option ( the one I'm asking about ). I can think of a work around but if this is possible I'd rather not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) with modified regular expression:

```
$rpl['brat'] = 'qwerty';
$rpl['omri'] = 'asdfgh';

$str1 = 'abc brat bca';
$str2 = 'abc omri bca';

print_r(preg_replace_callback('/bc (\w+) bc/', function($match) use($rpl) {
    return $rpl[$match[1]];
}, $str1)); // => abc qwerty bca

print_r("\n");

print_r(preg_replace_callback('/bc (\w+) bc/', function($match) use($rpl) {
    return $rpl[$match[1]];
}, $str1)); // => aqwertya
```

output:

```
abc qwerty bca
aqwertya
```

Comment: Why do you need to modify the regex

Comment: @php_nub_qq, `(+?)` is invalid regular expression. `+` required preceding pattern. I used `\w` to match any word character.

Comment: Yeah I just saw I missed the dots, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use flag 'e' , but that is NOT recommended because of it may cause secure problem

```
print_r(preg_replace('/bc (.+?) bc/e', '$rpl[$1]', $str1));
print_r(preg_replace('/bc (.+?) bc/e', '$rpl[$1]', $str2));
```